# Get input value if values is pregiven

Tags: javascript, html

This gives me back the original value of the input not the edited one.

```
<input type='text' value='test'>
this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value
```

The js event in on onchage

I have it like this right now and I am not getting the input of it...

```
var inputs=document.getElementById('wrap').getElementsByTagName('input');
        for (var i = inputs.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            inputs[i].onchange=function(){
                var x=this.parentNode.appendChild(document.createElement("a"));
                x.innerHTML="upravit";
                x.onclick=function(){
                    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    console.log(this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value);
```

Even the console.log itself gives me back the default value instead of the new one...

```
                        var vars = "menu=1&name=";
                        hr.open("POST", "Ajax/UpdateCategory.php", true);
                        hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                        hr.onreadystatechange = function(){
                            if(hr.readyState==4&&hr.status==200){
                                var return_data = hr.responseText;
                                if(return_data!="ok"){
                                    alert(return_data);
                                }
                            }
                        }
            hr.send(vars);
                    }
                }
            };
```

Comment: can you define whole `onchange()`?

Comment: What you want ? Please describe more.

Comment: I need to get the changed value of the input when I click on the <a> next to it

Comment: My bad got it working somehow... no idea how...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please  try this demo to learn onchange handler: http://www.w3school.com.cn/tiy/t.asp?f=hdom_onchange

and compare with this demo: http://www.w3school.com.cn/tiy/t.asp?f=hdom_onkeyup

Then you will know that, just use onkeyup() instead will work.

=== edited content ===
html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script>
        window.onload = function () {
            var inputs=document.getElementById('wrap').getElementsByTagName('input');
            var x=document.createElement("a");
            var data;
            x.innerHTML="upravit";
            x.onclick=function(){
                alert(data);
            }
            for (var i = inputs.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                inputs[i].onchange=function(){
                    this.parentNode.appendChild(x);
                    data = this.value;
                }
            }
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrap">
    <input type='text'>
    <input type='text'>
    <input type='text'>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please run this html in your local environment, I think this meet your needs.

Comment: I need to use onchange it works much better within my problem

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

html

```
<input type='text' value='test' onchange="dostuff(this)" />
```

js

```
function dostuff(s) {

    alert(s.value);

}
```

here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ac8P9/)

If this doesn't suit your case, please tell us how you are binding the js code in your question with the input in the html code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type='text' value='test' onchange="dostuff(this.value)" />

function dostuff(value) {    
    alert(value);    
}
```